# How to Disable javascript confirm box Server side Validation False button Submit Event?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

the user clicks the Save button in the form , 
i have to do some server side validation if server side validation false 
i want disable the javascript confirm box other wise enable javascript confirm box .
    my aspx code like this :

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" CssClass="blue-button" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddM" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
                                                        <Ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender8" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnSubmit" ConfirmText="Please Confirm">
    </Ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

[image]

Comment: JS Confirm is no validation at all. It's a confirmation alert.

Comment: @Rahul in the above image server side validation false .suppose  user will click submit button i don't want to show confirmation box . How to do like ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not an expert in ASP, but you could edit the "btnSubmit_Click" function to return false or throw an error if the validation fails. On the other hand I think you should clarify this question a bit more :)